# How to find folders with certain files and delete the folder?

Tags: script, batch-file

I'm looking for a way to find and remove every folder which contains files with extension .drt in it.

It's a networkshare and structure is shown below, in this case I want to delete subfolder 1 and 3

```
\\networkshare
  \\profiles
    \\001
    \\002
    \\003
      \\folder1
        \\subfolder1
          \\*.drt
      \\folder2
        \\subfolder2
      \\folder3
        \\subfolder3
          \\*.drt
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you first search for matching files, extract their path and then delete the path. This will work:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s *.drt') do @if exist %%F rd /s /q %%~dpF
```

The search command is just `dir`, the list is processed in a `FOR` loop, and the path extraction is done via `%%~dp`, i.e. only drive and path is extracted from each file found.
Note that removing the folder is only attempted after testing to avoid superfluous error messages.

Comment: will report "path not found" - Add `2> nul` to throw way the errors ...

Comment: Added code to avoid these messages but to keep real ones, e.g. permission denied. +1 for muting the command part with `@`.